# In a package I am building that, how can I leave handling of errors created by promises to consumers of the package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is a simple package I am building.

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

function createClient(host, port, body) {
    function httpRequestHelper(body, extractResponseCallback) {
        return fetch(`${host}:${port}`, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.type === 'error') {
                throw Error(response);
            }
            return extractResponseCallback(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });    
    }

    function recordings() {
        return httpRequestHelper({ type: 'request', cmd: 'recordings' });
    }

    return {
        recordings: recordings,
    };
}

exports.createClient = createClient;
```

I want the consumer of this package to be able to handle errors as htey see fit, for example as:

```
try {
    let recordingsResponse = await client.recordings()
    console.log(recordingsResponse);    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

However, with my current code I get the error:

```
(node:81180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at checkCreateProject (/Users/xp025106/Dev/qip-js-http-client/examples.js:15:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:81180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:81180) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
seldmac25073:qip-js-http-client xp025106$
```

How can I fix this?

PS. I have not written much code before that has been meant to be used by others, so any code improvement suggestions are welcome

Comment: `.catch(function(error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        })` is a no-op, don't do that. Also how is `client` declared in your example usage?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect consumers to handle error state themselves, the easiest solution is just to not catch any errors. You should handle errors that may expose sensitive information or errors caused by complex operations, however; it's probably a better idea to catch and re-throw (or reject) with a less descriptive error message instead of a full stack trace, or a more specific error message, in those cases.

It looks like your `httpRequestHelper` function expects two arguments: `body`, and  `extractResponseCallback`. Your exported `recording` function is only ever calling it with a single argument- hence the error about `undefined` not being a Function.

The solution is to export a closure, a bound function, or to delegate Function arguments to pass in the second argument that `httpRequestHelper` expects. In your case, delegating arguments is probably what you want, as closures and bound functions still need to be called a second time by your consumer.

## Closure

```
function recordings() {
  return function(callback) {
    return httpRequestHelper({ type: 'request', cmd: 'recordings' }, callback);
  };
}
```

## Bound Function

```
function recordings() {
  return httpRequestHelper.bind(null, { type: 'request', cmd: 'recordings' });
}
```

## Delegated arguments

```
function recordings(callback) {
  return httpRequestHelper({ type: 'request', cmd: 'recordings' }, callback);
}
```